What happened to SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean?
I have an old application that uses SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean from spring-context to call a remote EJB 3.0. After updating to the latest version (Spring 6.1.5 and Spring Boot 3.2.4) I noticed that the entire package that contains it (org.springframework.ejb) have been removed.
I tried to find some reference about this removal and couldn't find anything.
So what should I be using in the place of SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean?

The release notes of spring 6.1 mention the following:

EJB access has also been removed as part of this effort. If you need to lookup an EJB, use JNDI directly via JndiObjectFactoryBean or jee:jndi-lookup.

